# Is it possible to deploy changes to a Scheduled job using the metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, scheduled-job

Is it possible for us to deploy changes to a scheduled job using the metadata API? Is it a supported component? For example, I have a class that implements

```
Schedulable
```

and from the Salesforce UI, this class has been scheduled to run every day. Now, I would like to change this to run, say, once a week. Is there metadata that I can change for this? (We use the ANT migration tool for our deployments unless the changes are unsupported metadata types)

Comment: It's not clear actually what you are asking.Do you want to deploy changes using schedule jobs? or your only concern is to run schedule jobs once a week??

Comment: My main concern, is to ascertain if it is possible (given that a there already exists in production a scheduled job that runs apex at a certain time) to deploy changes (frequency, time when it executes etc.) to that scheduled job via the metadata API (as opposed to changing it in the Salesforce UI using the 'manage' link next to the job).

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you try to make changes to a scheduled job while it's scheduled to run, one known issue is that a job can get "stuck" and you won't be able to delete it from the queue. I would not recommend making changes to a scheulable while it's running. The only way to fix a "stuck" job like this is to file a case with Salesforce. In fact, it's a best practice to create an instance of the schedulable class rather than running the class itself. If you search the forum, you'll find several posts on this subject.